# If else is failing at the end and throwing key error - python

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, python-requests

This seem to have worked fine before but all of a sudden my code has stopped working. If else both runs successfully but then at the end it gives a key error.

The data here is coming from a json named as userdata.

Here is the code sample 1:

```
if(userdata["id"] == "Stage1"):
    for j in range(len(userdata['Data'])):
        if(userdata['Data'][j]['user']==userName):
            address=str(processdata['Data'][j]['address'])
            addressInst = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, address))
            print(addressInst)
        else:
            print('not available')
```

error:

```
KeyError: 'user'
```

I am getting the userName from the json which is obtained from an API and then I am calling another api to update its address. I am calling another API after this if statement, but I have hidden code from here because of reasons.

> `if(userdata['Data'][j]['user']==userName):`

I am able to call the API successfully but at the end I get the above mentioned error everytime and hence my function fails to run.

I actually want to avoid if else, Can anyone tell me how can I save the matching data

```
userdata['Data'][j]['user']==userName
```

and then call API to update data accordingly so I can avoid the error?

Comment: You appear to already know your dictionary doesn't contain a "user" key. You haven't included anything that would help diagnose why that is.  I'm not sure what answer you're looking for

Comment: The KeyError simply means that you are using [] to access a dictionary key that does not exist in your data. In this case, there is no "user" key in the dict userdata['Data'][j]. You really should be careful to check if keys may be missing in your code and have your code do something else when they are.

Comment: KeyError raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys, you are trying to index a value, thats why its happenning

Comment: Is there any way to store json of userdata['Data'][j]['user']==userName and avoid if else?

Comment: I don' care about the user not matching, I just need matching users data from that json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access a non-existent key in the JSON. Use `get` to return a default value if the key does not exist:

```
if(userdata["id"] == "Stage1"):
    for data in userdata['Data']:
        if (data.get('user') == userName):
            address = data.get('address', [])
            addressInst = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, address))
            print(addressInst)
        else:
            print('Not available')
```

Or a shorter version without the `if ... else ...`:

```
if(userdata["id"] == "Stage1"):
    for data in filter(lambda d: d.get('user') == userName, userdata['Data']):
        address = data.get('address', [])
        addressInst = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, address))
        print(addressInst)
```

Here what it does:

- `filter` returns an *iterator* for items in the list where the lambda returns True
- `d.get('user')` returns None if the key 'user' cannot be found in `d` instead of erroring out.

Unless you are sure the dictionary will contain a key, it's always better to call `aDict.get(key, defaultValue)` to avoid errors.

Comment: Hey, You are awesome. The second version of your code did exactly what I needed but Can you please provide some explanation on it?

Comment: Hey, How do I add another condition in the filter()?

Comment: `lambda d: (d.get('user') == userName) and (...)`

Comment: It accepts "and" not "&"?

Comment: `and` is the logical-and. `&` is the bitwise-and

Answer (score 1):

Before comparing the values from an unknown dictionary, we should always check if the key is present. I follow this when dealing with api responses.

Here is how you can do it:

```
if(userdata["id"] == "Stage1"):
    for j in range(len(userdata['Data'])):
        if 'user' in userdata['Data'][j].keys() and (userdata['Data'][j]['user']==userName):
            address=str(processdata['Data'][j]['address'])
            addressInst = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, address))
            print(addressInst)
        else:
            print('Either the key user is not present or the values do not match.')
```

As you say before it was working and now the same code is not.

This might have happened because of change in the api response. Earlier it was giving some different JSOn data and now it is different.

Comment: This seems to work for me and I longer get the error after using this but can you tell me if I can store the matching key values in another json and then call the api? rather than using if else?

Comment: I did not understand the question brother to be frank. Can you please elaborate a little? What json and what matching key value?

Comment: Hey Prashant, please check the second version of @Code Different's answers, It is what I wanted to do

Comment: Great to hear your problem was solved. He did a good work understanding your json structure. Cheers bro.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code did solve 90% of my problem

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the algorithm to stop when running on API, in case of failed request, I use the try statement, here is one example.

```
a = [0, 1, 2]

for _ in a:
  print(1/_)

out:
error
1.0
0.5
```

Without try statement, the algorithm break.

```
a = [0, 1, 2]

for _ in a:
  print(1/_)

out: 
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Use try for every request, if it fails, you won't have to restart.